# How to submit form with concatenated URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm fairly new to the whole Javascript scene. Followed along with those online javascript tutorial things like code academy offers so I'm going by what I learned off of there and what I have read through other tutorials. Read though a few other posts to try and help me but I can't figure it out

So here's my question,

I am trying to take a form input, send it to a javascript file, then the javascript file returns a string which then I wish to reload the frame with. I'm attempting to make a simple chrome extension for me and my friends.

When I click "View Grade!" I get an error:

```
No webpage was found for the web address: chrome-extension://gcgddggimojbfgpbdmpfkmiofmpinjgb/location.href=getURL(account)?
```

and I can't determine if my javascript isn't working right or I just don't know how to send to a URL outside the "chromium" (as I call it) world.

This is my html file:

```
<form action="location.href=getURL('account')">
    PSU Account (i.e. xyz123): <input type:"text" id="account">
   <input type="submit" value="View Grade!">
</form>
```

And this is my javascript file:

```
function getURL(account) {
    var psuAccount = document.getElementById(psuAccount);
    // I changed strA to the ***.***.*** for this post
    var strA = 'https://***.***.***/section/Gradebook/Student/default.aspx?userId=';
    var strB = '&reportMode=true';
    var newURL = strA + psuAccount + strB);
    return(newURL);
}
```

Comment: `<input type:"text" id="account">` should be `<input type="text" id="account">` - notice I changed `type:` to `type=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is exactly what `<form>`s are for...no need for Javascript for something like this. Try:

```
<form action="https://***.***.***/section/Gradebook/Student/default.aspx" method="GET">
    PSU Account (i.e. xyz123): <input type="text" name="userId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="reportMode" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" value="View Grade!" />
</form>
```

The submit mechanism will automatically use the `action` attribute of the form. Since the `method` is "GET", it will also add a querystring of key/value pairs for elements in the `<form>` with a `name` attribute. So with your form, it will add a key "userId" with the value as the textbox's current value at time of submission. It will also add a key "reportMode" with the value "true". So the final URL that will be submitted is:

```
https://***.***.***/section/Gradebook/Student/default.aspx?userMode=true&userId=SOME_INPUT_STRING
```

If you need to use Javascript, try:

```
<div>
    PSU Account (i.e. xyz123): <input type:"text" id="account" />
    <input type="button" value="View Grade!" onclick="getURL();" />
</div>
```

with:

```
function getURL() {
    var psuAccount = document.getElementById("account").value;
    var strA = 'https://***.***.***/section/Gradebook/Student/default.aspx?userId=';
    var strB = '&reportMode=true';
    var newURL = strA + psuAccount + strB;
    window.location.href = newURL;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I couldn't get the javascript you wrote to work but the original `<form>` worked perfectly! You explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: @pattmorter Cool, glad it worked for you! I don't know if you would've fixed it, but I accidentally left a `)` in the Javascript (so that made sense why it didn't work). I just edited the answer, so if you wanted to try it again, I would hope it works now. Either way, I'd suggest using the `<form>` example anyways :)

Comment: I like the `<form>` example best myself. Just wanted to give the js a try out of curiosity.